# Jquery - Add hyperlink to datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, datatables

Using the DataTable plugin I am able to generate a table just fine but I want a custom hyperlink on one of the columns that links to another page but taking information from the rest of the row...for example in row 1 I want a hyperlink: http://url/?data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["code"] or something like that. I've seen a lot of complicated examples from other forms but couldn't get it to work. Looking for the simplest solution as this is a side project and I need it to be completed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON('/static/faults.json', function (data) {

            var test = $('#table5').DataTable({
            });

            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < data["totalCount"]; i++) {
              test.row.add([
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["code"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["cause"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["descr"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["created"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["changeSet"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["childAction"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["dn"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["domain"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["highestSeverity"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["lastTransition"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["lc"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["occur"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["origSeverity"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["prevSeverity"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["rule"],
                  "test",
                  //data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["Severity"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["subject"],
                  data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']["attributes"]["type"],
                  //data['imdata'][i]['faultInst']['attributes']["ack"]
                  "test",
                  "test"
              ])
            }

            test.draw();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I can't tell from reading the code what result you're getting. Do you see the correct text in the cell? If so, is the text a hyperlink? (Can't see how there is) and the link does not load correctly or does not work at all?

Comment: This is the code for just the table and pulling the info from a json file. I want to know how to add a hyperlink to one of the columns.

Comment: To be clear there is no code that adds a hyperlink...that's what i'm looking for as every solution I've seen doesn't work for my case.

here is something that turn the column into a bunch of download links but I can't get it to work for me.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

    $('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
    }
  } ]
} );

Comment: I think `render` isn't working because you're not using the datatables API to populate your table. Can you not simply construct a link in the for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a setup like this, just avoid to define `data`, by that you get the proper value you can turn into a link. dataTables know which data it should pass to the render function by the `targets` value. Example :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs : [
      { targets : [0],
        render : function(data) {
          return '<a href="'+data+'" target_blank>'+data+'</a>'
        } 
      }
    ]
})  

table.row.add(['https://example.com', 'david', 'programmer']).draw()
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/47k7nhkb/**

Comment: UGH THIS IS SO SIMPLE! I feel dumb...Thanks a lot!