# How to put hyperlink in jquery datatables plugin in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am using DataTables to generate a table. There is a column containing username

For example: ...

I need every row in this column to have a hyperlink when anyone clicks on username then it redirects to edit page, For example, the first row would be a hyperlink to view?id=1321755 etc.

What is the simplest way I can do so?

Here is my code of view:

```
<table id="book-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
     <thead>
     <tr class="">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Work</th>
      <th>Partner</th>
      <th>Director</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
     </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#book-table').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url : "<?php echo site_url("digital_admin/hodm/books_page") ?>",
            type : 'GET'
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public function books_page()
     {

          // Datatables Variables
          $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
          $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
          $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));


          $books = $this->pojo->get_books();

          $data = array();

          foreach($books->result() as $r) {

               $data[] = array(
                    $r->user_name,
                    $r->date,
                    $r->t_name,
                    $r->partner,
                    $r->director,
                    $r->duration,
                    $r->task,
                    $r->status
               );
          }

          $output = array(
               "draw" => $draw,
                 "recordsTotal" => $books->num_rows(),
                 "recordsFiltered" => $books->num_rows(),
                 "data" => $data
            );
          echo json_encode($output);
          exit();
     }
```

Kindly help me to find the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Add hyperlink to datatables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024933/jquery-add-hyperlink-to-datatables)

Comment: @markpsmith link which you mention is only for one row and my problem for lots of rows which fetched from database

Comment: Easiest is to put the link already in the query something like: `'<a href="view?id='. $r->user_id .'" >'. $r->user_name .'</a>'`;

Comment: @MichaelK I didn't get you . how i add link and where

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to put it directly in the array something like:

```
      foreach($books->result() as $r) {

           $data[] = array(
                '<a href="/view?id='.$r->user_id.'" >'. $r->user_name .'</a>',
                $r->date,
                $r->t_name,
                $r->partner,
                $r->director,
                $r->duration,
                $r->task,
                $r->status
           );
      }
```

But be aware that the sorting on such column in DataTables may not apply to the actual username shown, but the whole content string. Replace `/view?id='.$r->user_id.'` in the above example with the id and url you want to use.

Note that `json_encode()` escapes some characters, for instance the double quotes, so you might need to do add backslash before them:

```
'<a href=\"/view?id='.$r->user_id.'\" >'. $r->user_name .'</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Thanx for the help.

Here is the final code which is working.

```
$data[] = array(
                    '<a href="edit_hodm/'.$r->id.'" >'. $r->user_name .'</a>',
                    $r->date,
                    $r->t_name,
                    $r->partner,
                    $r->director,
                    $r->duration,
                    $r->task,
                    $r->status
               );
```

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept my answer if it worked for you